# java.sql.SQLException: "pos" argument can not be < 1

Tags: java, blob

I encountered this error when trying to convert a blob from a database to an image.  I've tried searching for the solution, but I couldn't find anything.  The exception is thrown when calling:

```
sampleBlob.getBinaryStream(0, (int) sampleBlob.length())
```

The rest of the code:

```
String sql = "Select * from users where `UserID` = '"+id+"'";
Statement s2 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet studentData = s2.executeQuery(sql);
studentData.next();
Blob imageBlob = studentData.getBlob("Image");

try {
    in = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(0, (int) imageBlob.length());
    img = ImageIO.read(in);
    finalImg = new ImageIcon(img);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    finalImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/default.png"));
}
```

The exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: "pos" argument can not be < 1.   
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Blob.getBinaryStream(Blob.java:340)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream(long,%20long)):

> pos - the offset to the first byte of the partial value to be
>   retrieved. The first byte in the Blob is at position **1**

you need start from `1`, not `0`.